# How can I configure retry logic for the specific transaction using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core for working with a database in my .NET core project.

I use a transaction while doing some requests (I'm using the `ResilientTransaction` pattern from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-resilient-entity-framework-core-sql-connections#execution-strategies-and-explicit-transactions-using-begintransaction-and-multiple-dbcontexts)), so my code looks something like this:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action)
{
    var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

    await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        await action();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    });
}
```

Is there a build-in way to configure a retry logic for this (and only this) transaction?

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency#option-3---add-state-verification) option in MS documentation:

```
    strategy.ExecuteInTransaction(
        db,
        operation: context => { context.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess: false); },
        verifySucceeded: context => context.Blogs.AsNoTracking().Any(b => b.BlogId == blogToAdd.BlogId));
```

However, it configures only the behaviour, but I want to adjust the amount of attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the strategy explicitly, eg:

```
var strategy = new SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(_context, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you! I use Postgres, so based on your answer it was easy to google: var strategy = new NpgsqlRetryingExecutionStrategy(_context, 4)